# Arrays/PHP - i have a problem for displaying my array correctly

Tags: php, arrays, model-view-controller

This is my problem, one array is display in one column of my table :

[image]

I want to display,for exemple, each evt_id in the same columne of my table, and so on. Thanks in advance if you have an idea about my problem :)

QUERY :

```
public function getSuiviFluTech($idDepot){
     $this->executeQueries("
     Select evt_id, evt_dt, evt_nomfic, evt_statut, evt_texte from depot_evt 
     where id_depot = ".$idDepot."
     order by evt_dt desc"
             );
     return $this->getAllRows();
```

CONTROLLER :

```
if ($depotExist) {
        $this->view->idDepot = $idDepot;
        $oDepotAdmin = new Services_DepotAdmin();
        $listDepotAdmin = $oDepotAdmin->getSuiviFluTech($idDepot);
        if (count($listDepotAdmin) >= 1) {
            $this->view->listdepotdrpadmin = $listDepotAdmin;
```

HTML :

```
<table id="supervisionResDepotDrp">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="center">EVT_ID</th>
                        <th class="center">EVT_DT</th>
                        <th class="center">EVT_NOMFIC</th>
                        <th class="center">EVT_STATUT</th>
                        <th class="center">EVT_TEXTE</th>
                        <th class="center">DOWNLOAD</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <?php 
    // Le 7ème champ statut_depot n'est pas affiché, car il sert uniquement pour les RG
    // Il est redondantt avec le 6ème qui est sa traduction en langage humain
                        $i=0; 

                        foreach ($this->listdepotdrpadmin as $elem) { ?>
                        <td class="center"><?php if ($i++ < count($this->listdepotdrpadmin)) print_r ($elem); ?></td>

                      <?php }
```

Comment: `<?=$elem['evt_id']?>` and go on.

Comment: Add your `<tr>`... `</tr>` tags into the `foreach` loop...

Comment: thanks for your answer @u_mulder, but it's not working, when i put this on my loop, i have one evt_id for each column. I want one evt_id for each line.

Comment: Thanks for your answer you too @UsagiMiyamoto but its not working too. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<tbody>
    <?php 
    foreach ($this->listdepotdrpadmin as $elem) {?>
    <tr>
        <td class="center"><?=$elem['evt_id']?></td>
        <td class="center"><?=$elem['evt_dt']?></td>
        <td class="center"><?=$elem['evt_nomfic']?></td>
        <td class="center"><?=$elem['evt_status']?></td>
        <td class="center"><?=$elem['evt_text']?></td>
        <td class="center">-</td>
    </tr>
    <?php 
    }?>
</tbody>
```